# Rails mock_model returning TrueClass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocking, rspec, functional-testing

Trying to test a controller in Rspec. (Rails 2.3.8, Ruby 1.8.7, Rspec 1.3.1, Rspec-Rails 1.3.3)

I'm trying to post a create but I get this error message:

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in 'ProjectsController with appropriate parameters while logged in:  should create project'
    User(#2171994580) expected, got TrueClass(#2148251900)

My test code is as follows:

```
def mock_user(stubs = {})
  @user = mock_model(User, stubs)
end

def mock_project(stubs = {})
  @project = mock_model(Project, stubs)
end

def mock_lifecycletype(stubs = {})
  @lifecycletype = mock_model(Lifecycletype, stubs)
end

it "should create project" do
  post :create, :project => { :name => "Mock Project", 
    :description => "Mock Description",
    :owner => @user,
    :lifecycletype => mock_lifecycletype({ :name => "Mock Lifecycle" }) }
  assigns[:project].should == mock_project({ :name => "Mock Project",
    :description => "Mock Description",
    :owner => mock_user,
    :lifecycletype => mock_lifecycletype({ :name => "Mock Lifecycle" })})
  flash[:notice].should == "Project was successfully created."
end
```

The trouble comes when I try to do `:owner => @user` in the code above. For some reason, it thinks that my @user is `TrueClass` instead of a `User` class object. Funny thing is, if I comment out the `post :create` code, and I do a simple `@user.class.should == User`, it works, meaning that @user is indeed a `User` class object.

I've also tried

```
:owner => mock_user
:owner => mock_user({ :name => "User",
  :email => "user@email.com",
  :password => "password",
  :password_confirmation => "password })
:owner => @current_user
```

Note @current_user is also mocked out as a user, which I tested (the same way, `@current_user.class.should == User`) and also returns a `TrueClass` when I try to set :owner.

Anybody have any clue why this is happening?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you are not creating your instance variable, `@user` before referencing it in the `post` statement. You would do well to create the instance variables prior to the post so the preconditions are immediately obvious. That way you could know whether `@user` had been set.

I know some people prefer the one-line-of-code-is-better-because-i'm-smart method of writing stuff like this, but I've found being explicit and even repetitive is a really good idea, particularly in tests.

I'm adding the following code that I believe may express your intent better that what you have. In my code, I use mock expectations to "expect" a `Project` is created with a particular set of parameters. I believe your code assumes that you can do an equality comparison between a newly-created mock Project and a different one created during execution of your controller. That may not be true because they are distinctly different objects.

In my code, if you have a problem with something evaluating to TrueClass or the like, you can use a line of code like `user.should be_a(User)` to the example to make sure stuff is wired up correctly.

```
def mock_user(stubs = {})
  mock_model(User, stubs)
end

def mock_project(stubs = {})
  mock_model(Project, stubs)
end

def mock_lifecycletype(stubs = {})
  mock_model(Lifecycletype, stubs)
end

it "should create project" do
  user = mock_user
  owner = user
  lifecycletype = mock_lifecycletype({ :name => "Mock Lifecycle" })

  # Not certain what your params to create are, but the argument to with
  # is what the params are expected to be
  Project.should_receive(:create).once.with({:user => user, :owner => owner, :lifecycletype => lifecycletype})

  post :create, :project => { :name => "Mock Project", 
    :description => "Mock Description",
    :owner => @user,
    :lifecycletype => lifecycletype }
  flash[:notice].should == "Project was successfully created."
end
```

Comment: As a side note, it's possible that setting expectations would be more effective than testing equality. Testing equality opens a question of "what does == mean in this context?".

Comment: Ah, so sorry! I am creating the user. I have a before(:each) block that sets up everything I need. Also, I found the problem. In my controller, I have a line that sets: @project.owner = current_user.... If I change that to @project.owner_id = current_user.id, everything works. Strange.